# puppet: puppetDB and templatedir

Tags: puppet

I installed some puppet server and puppetDB:

```
    [root@her code]# puppet master --version
    4.3.1
    [root@her code]# uname -a
    Linux her 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    [root@her code]# cat /etc/centos-release
    CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) 
    [root@her code]# rpm -qa | grep pupp
    puppetlabs-release-pc1-1.0.0-1.el7.noarch
    puppet-agent-1.3.2-1.el7.x86_64
    puppetserver-2.2.1-1.el7.noarch
    [root@her code]# puppet module list
    /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
    +-- puppetlabs-apt (v2.2.1)
    +-- puppetlabs-concat (v1.2.5)
    +-- puppetlabs-firewall (v1.7.2)
    +-- puppetlabs-inifile (v1.4.3)
    +-- puppetlabs-postgresql (v4.6.1)
    +-- puppetlabs-puppetdb (v5.0.0)
    L-- puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.10.0)
    /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules (no modules installed)
    /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

this [man](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppetserver/2.2/install_from_packages.html)
and now i have some questions:

1. How to know than puppetDB is work? I can't see it in 'ps ax' output, that's ok?

   ```
   [root@her code]# ps ax | grep pupp | grep -v grep
   23423 ?        Ssl    1:41 /usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d -b /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg

   [root@her code]# ps ax | grep sql | grep -v grep
   ```
2. Where i can set templatedir? In puppet 3.8 it's done in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf, but in this version i dunno where is this set...

Answer (score 0):

Concerning `templatedir`, that is a concept that was actually deprecated in Puppet `3.8`. It did not carry over to Puppet `4.x`.

You want to switch to [directory environments](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.8/reference/environments_configuring.html) where each module has its own stash of templates. It's not a good practice to use templates outside of modules.

Comment: Thx, i find an answer: http://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/22783/puppetdb-templatedir/